# Ensure PHP/MySQL code is executed in one go?

Tags: php, mysql, execute

Is there a way to ensure the below code, is executed in one go (so if the visitor presses escape on keyboard or closes browser, it won't just execute half way. It's important they are all done in one go or none at all).

```
mysql_query($queryone);

mysql_query($querytwo);

unlink($file);

unlink($thumb);

mysql_query($querythree);
```

Appreciate all replies and example code would be nice.

Comment: Does it take a while to execute?

Comment: @PeteHerbertPenito not it's quite fast (but saying that...im testing on local...where I don't have much data).

Comment: You probably want to read about [*transactions*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html). Further, please don't use `mysql_*` functions - it's deprecated and not safe! Better use MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: The user closing their browser or hitting escape or whatever will have no effect on aborting your script.

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm not sure if that's 100% accurate, I have a script that executes about 400 transactions, and if I stop it after a few seconds, only a few of them will complete, and the remaining transactions will not complete. But then again, this is doing a lot of processing per transaction. (script can run for up to 2 minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are those statements would all execute if the user stopped their browser, but to ensure that they do, add [`ignore_user_abort(true);`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) before those statements to tell PHP not to terminate if it detects a client disconnect.

See the `php.ini` setting [ignore_user_abort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.ignore-user-abort).  This will allow the script to run to completion whether or not the client is still connected.

Further reading:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php

Comment: plus running the queries in a transaction, though if PHP fails, rolling back the database but still completing the php stuff partiall could be bad.

Comment: @MikeBrant It works for browser connections as well.  See docs.

Comment: Yea assuming that what is posted is the complete script and not a simplification.  Either way, enabling this setting will safely allow the script to run to completion regardless of various factors (barring consideration of max_execution_time).

Comment: @drew010 for ignore_user_abort to work; would it mean echo'ing something to the visitor?, also once all the code following the ignore_user_abort function call executes....i'm guessing thats the end of it (it won't be running in the background or anything will it?), slightly confused..hope you can reply.

Comment: @user962026 If you never echo anything to the browser, then the script won't terminate until it finishes regardless of whether or not the client has disconnected.  For safety, adding ignore_user_abort will allow it to run to completion even if the user does disconnect.  Once it reaches the end then the script terminates, ignore_user_abort won't make the script hang around, only allows it to keep running in the event of a disconnect.  And you don't have to echo anything to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You might need mysql transactions. These functions (Commit, rollback etc) will undo query's on brakedown when not all query's are succesfull.
[Mysql transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 1):

> so if the visitor presses escape on keyboard or closes browser, it won't just execute half way

The visitor closing the browser or pressing escape (or any key for that matter) will have no effect on the script running on your server. Your script will finish running regardless of what the client does.

> its important they are all done in one go or none at all

You should definitely take a look at [MySQL Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html). You may also want to consider putting the transaction in a [stored procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines.html).